# XSLT link between two elements that share the same value and print the linked data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've started learning xml/xslt and xsl-fo and while doing some basic exercises I've got myself into a small issue.

I am trying to link the books to their category price using `<category>` and  `<priceCategory>` . Not sure what to search for, while browsing stackoverflow I found that I can use a key, like this.

```
<xsl:key name="link" match="priceCategory" use="priceCategory"/>
```

and print the value using

```
<xsl:for-each select="bookstore/books/mybook">
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="key('link', money/prices/price)/priceCategory"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I had no success so far, anyone can help me with some documentation or an example/explanation, I think I am not searching for the right thing, I can't find the right word for this type of problem.

This is an example XML:

```
<bookstore>
      <books>
            <mybook>
                  <name>bookname1</name>
                  <pages>350</pages>
                  <category>A</category>
            </book>
            <mybook>
                  <name>bookname2</name>
                  <pages>150</pages>
                  <category>B</category>
            </book>
            <mybook>
                  <name>bookname3</name>
                  <pages>450</pages>
                  <category>B</category>
            </book>
            <mybook>
                  <name>bookname4</name>
                  <pages>550</pages>
                  <category>C</category>
            </book>
      <books>
      <money>
            <prices>
                  <price>50</price>
                  <priceCategory> A </priceCategory>
            </prices>
            <prices>
                  <price>100</price>
                   <priceCategory> B </priceCategory>                  
            </prices>
            <prices>
                  <price>150</price>
                  <priceCategory> C </priceCategory>                 
            </prices>
      </money>
</bookstore>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Your xml is not wellformed. Your open tag: <prices>, your close tag: </price>

Comment: Sorry, edited it now, I posted that just as an example, I don't have access to the original XML until weekend. This was written on my tablet, there might be other typo.

Comment: Should we consider whitespace differences between <category>A</category> and <priceCategory> A </priceCategory>?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to show the price of the category? If yes, you could use this:

```
<xsl:key name="link" match="prices" use="priceCategory"/>
```

This key wil match on prices using priceCategory when calling the key as "filter" .

```
<xsl:for-each select="bookstore/books/mybook">
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="key('link', category)/price"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I want to show the name of the book and the corresponding price to the book's category.
Example: bookname1 is in category A, this means the book's price is 50, because A's priceCategory is 50.

I'll try the code above and check if I can make it work :) Thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: This will do then....depending a the comment I made to your question about whitespace